# How to link between Authenticated users and Database in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have Firebase Authentication in my Android app. My question is how do I link between authenticated users (that appear in `Firebase::Auth` tab in the Firebase console) and the database (`Firebase::Database` tab).

I need to link data in the database with the relevant user in `Auth` by the `User UID` that appears in `Auth`, and eventually send queries about a specific `UID` to get the relevant info in `Database`.

Is there something automatic / built-in that does that or do I have to create a new entry for a user in `Database` each time I authenticate a user and then create an ID field for it with the UID value that appears in `Auth`?

In the [User Management docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400802) it explains only about adding users to the `Auth` tab and resetting their passwords.

Comment: You'll need to write the code to store the user profile in the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/39444060, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39439459, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276447,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I link each user to their data in Firebase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910704/how-do-i-link-each-user-to-their-data-in-firebase)

Comment: @André Kool this looks like javascript... I'm asking about Android

Comment: I know but the principle is exactly the same, instead of the web docs for reading and writing data you can take a look at [the android docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write). The first example you see there should be about saving user data.

Comment: @AndréKool I'm not struggling with writing... I was wondering if there's a built in way to map between the UID's and the database... Seems like there's no built in thing. The solution is like I said in my question (and now I posted an answer)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After authentication, create a child with the UID given by Firebase, and set its value to your user class:

```
//get firebase user
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

//get reference
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USERS_TABLE);

//build child
ref.child(user.getUid()).setValue(user_class);
```

USERS_TABLE is a direct child of root.

Then when you want to retrieve the data, get a reference to the user by its UID, listen for `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` (invoked only once), and iterate over the result with reflection:

```
//get firebase user
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

//get reference
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USERS_TABLE).child(user.getUid());
//IMPORTANT: .getReference(user.getUid()) will not work although user.getUid() is unique. You need a full path!

//grab info
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final Profile tempProfile = new Profile(); //this is my user_class Class
        final Field[] fields = tempProfile.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field : fields){
            Log.i(TAG, field.getName() + ": " + dataSnapshot.child(field.getName()).getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

**edit:**

Or without reflection:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    final Profile p = dataSnapshot.getValue(Profile.class);
}
```